# How do I get ASP.NET MVC to set a default Controller and Action for an Area?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, areas

I've created a new ASP.NET MVC project with areas and I'm trying to set a controller action to be the default controller action if the user visits that area.

I added an area called 'Login' now I have `Areas/Login/` and I added `LoginController`.

I am trying to set this controller to be invoked when the user navigates to the website. 
I can access it if I type in browser `www.test.com/Login/Login` but I don't know how to set routing in `global.asax` to point to this controller as the default.

How do I do that in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140208/how-to-set-a-default-route-to-an-area-in-mvc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you created your area, did MVC not create the `[AreaName]AreaRegistration` class under the Areas/[AreaName] folder?  In there you will find the area registration that looks similar to this.  Modify the `controller =` portion of the defaults parameter to the controller name (Login) you want to use by default:

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Login_default",
            "Login/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you decorate your HomeController (or really, all of your controllers that require someone to be logged in) with the `[Authorize]` attribute, ASP.NET MVC will automatically redirect people to the login screen if they are not logged in.

Example usage:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Home()
{
}
```

Also, you may want to read up on the [Open Redirect attack vulnerability (and fix)](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/01/25/preventing-open-redirection-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

Comment: I put login here as an example. My main question is how to set routing to start some controller as a default if that controller is in area.