# How register routes type Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I automatic register routes for modules and trying to register routes for admin.
For modules registration working fine

```
public class ModulSetup : BaseModule
{
    public override void Setup()
    {
        this.SetupViewEngine();
        this.SetupControllers();
    }

    public override void SetupRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            string.Empty,
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    }

    protected override void SetupViewEngine()
    {
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CoreViewEngine());
    }

    protected override void SetupControllers()
    {
        ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("SGN.Core.Controllers");
    }
}
```

But for admin, I get 404

```
public class AdminSetup : BaseModule
{
    public override void Setup()
    {
        this.SetupViewEngine();
        this.SetupControllers();
    }

    public override void SetupRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Admin",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Site", action = "Index" });

    protected override void SetupViewEngine()
    {
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new AdminViewEngine());
    }

    protected override void SetupControllers()
    {
        ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("SGN.Core.Admin.Controllers");
    }
}
```

Example. I have controllers class Site

```
namespace SGN.Core.Admin.Controllers
{
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SGN.Framework.Controller;

public class SiteController : AdminController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View();
    }
}
}
```

And when I try go to http://localhost:777/Admin/Site/ server return 404 :(

**UPDATE**

I try create AreaAwareViewEngine ho write thee [How to set a Default Route (To an Area) in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140208/how-to-set-a-default-route-to-an-area-in-mvc)

But not help

**UPDATE**

I try use this url http://localhost:777/Admin/Site/Index work. But this not good. And Master not work.

**UPDATE**

I use RouteDebugger for check in other project where I use Area. What add when use Area. How I understand in DataTokens Add 3 parameters

*Namespaces = SGN.Web.Areas.Admin.*, area = Admin, UseNamespaceFallback = False*

I try add this parameters

*Namespaces = SGN.Core.Admin.*, area = Admin, UseNamespaceFallback = False*

But not help

**UPDATE**

I created the class AreaAwareViewEngine how write here [How to set a Default Route (To an Area) in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140208/how-to-set-a-default-route-to-an-area-in-mvc)

My class AreaRegistration

```
namespace SGN.Web.Admin
  {
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
   {
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {area="Admin", controller = "Site", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
}
```

And create AdminViewEngine from AreaAwareViewEngine

```
namespace SGN.Core.Admin
{
using System.Web.Mvc;

using SGN.Framework;

public class AdminViewEngine : AreaAwareViewEngine
{
    public AdminViewEngine()
    {
        AreaMasterLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Admin/Views/Shared/admin.cshtml" };

        AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Admin/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml", "~/Admin/Menu/{0}.cshtml" };

        AreaViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Admin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Admin/Menu/{0}.cshtml" };

        ViewLocationFormats = AreaViewLocationFormats;
        PartialViewLocationFormats = AreaPartialViewLocationFormats;
        MasterLocationFormats = AreaMasterLocationFormats;
    }

    protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        return new RazorView(controllerContext, partialPath, null, false, FileExtensions);
    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(masterPath))
        {
            masterPath = AreaMasterLocationFormats[0];
        }
        var view = new RazorView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath, true, FileExtensions);
        return view;
    }
}
  }
```

Work if i go to http://localhost:777/Admin/Site/ and not work if I go to http://localhost:777/Admin

Answer (score 0):

It could be a simple ordering issue.  Are your Admin routes added before your Core routes? I believe that it will take the first matching route and unless your Admin route is added before the others, I suspect one of them is matching and it is being redirected to an Admin controller (which doesn't exist).  You might want to look at it with Haack's [RouteDebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx).

Also, is there any reason you're not using the built-in areas feature? This seems like a perfect match for that.

Comment: Route for Admin in RouteCollection ranks second.  And I cannot test routes use RouteDebugger. because return 404

Comment: I'm not used areas because I don't want use folder area

Answer (score 0):

First off, ensure that your "Admin" route is mapped before your default non-Admin route.  Also, I'd change your Admin route to this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Admin",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Site", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

That way, the `id` route parameter has a default value of being `UrlParameter.Optional`.  Your initial route didn't have a default for `id`, so it would be requiring it.

Comment: @Greg put this route before your default route.

Comment: Route for Admin in RouteCollection ranks second. First routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");