# Controller & View In separated assembly in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to separate View and Controller in different Dll and call them from MVC project

I tried to take reference from dll into mvc project and i could use controller but i can't return View from dll 
 and tried make custom razorviewengine but also didn't work

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341336/mvc-views-located-in-another-project