# ASP NET 5 Localization using View components in a separate assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a "Class Library" project with some "ViewComponents" on it and I already made them work on my "MVC 6 Web app" ([thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236850/asp-net-mvc-6-view-components-in-a-separate-assembly)) but now I'm trying to add language resources (localization) to my "ViewComponents". Any suggestion on how this should be done?.

I already added the necesary lines to the startup file on my "MVC 6 Web app":

**startup.cs**

```
[...]
services.AddMvc()
        .AddViewLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
[...]
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestCulture(new CultureInfo("es-MX")));
```

Also I added the dependencies on my "Class Library" Views:

**Views/Shared/Components/Header/foo.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer LocString
<h1>@LocString["HelloWorld"]</h1>
```

and created the Resource folder and file in my "Class Library" project:

```
-Resources
   -Views.Shared.Components.Header.foo.cshtml.resx
```

but all I get is the name of the key "HelloWorld" instead of the localized resource "Hola mundo"

In short Am I missing something? Does anyone knows a way to use localized resources in "view components" from a "class library" on a "mvc 6 web app"

Notes:

- I'm using mvc 6 RC1
- Resources from other views that are not ViewComponents are working fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't know the name of the resource file the compiler was looking for when accessing from a view component, so following [this thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/153) I used the IStringLocalizerFactory directly:

```
public class HeaderViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
  private string viewName;
  private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

  public HeaderViewComponent(IStringLocalizerFactory localizedFactory)
  {
     _localizer = localizedFactory.Create("name.of.your.resource.file", "Namespace");
  } 
  public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
  {
    [...]
    ViewBag.StringLocalizer = _localizer;
    return View("name", model);
  }
}
```

The second parameter of "Create" is the namespace of your "class library"

Then in my Invoke function I added the _localizer to the ViewBag to use it on the view (since I havent found a way to inject the IViewLocalizer using the localizedFactory I just created).

Also I added this to my "class library" project.json:

```
"resource": [ "Views/**", "Resources/**" ]
```

Hope it helps others looking for a solution to use resources on a class library