# EditorTemplate templates in a separate assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-assembly, class-library, mvc-editor-templates

Is it possible to configure an ASP.NET Core web application to use `EditorTemplate` razor pages that are compiled into a class library/separate assembly?

As an example, the following question details how a `ViewComponent` can be compiled into a class library. Unfortunately I can't find any information about doing the same with `EditorTemplate` pages.

[ASP.NET MVC 6: view components in a separate assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236850/asp-net-mvc-6-view-components-in-a-separate-assembly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this with help from *pranavkm* on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5703). The steps I required were as follows:

**In the web application:** in `ConfigureServices()` add the class module assembly as a file provider (get the assembly through the type of any class or interface within the assembly):

```
var library = typeof(Library.SomeClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(library));
    });
```

**In the class module:** ensure the directory structure that contains your editor templates is the same as it would be in your web application `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates`.

**In the class module:** embed the razor views as a resource by adding the following to your `project.json`:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "embed": "Views/**"
}
```

Comment: What dependencies are needed for the class library? How is the tooling experience in vs2017 when working inside these cshtml files vs working in view files in an actual mvc project - any difference?

Comment: Intellisense works fine (though see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804844/class-library-lost-intellisense-in-vs2017-after-net-core-mvc-auto-migration). You have to manually rebuild after making changes - Roslyn doesn't pick up on things automatically. Precompilation of the razor views in a class library is also pretty broken at the moment. On the dependency front just adding a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` ought to be enough.