# Class library lost intellisense in VS2017 after .NET Core MVC auto-migration

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, intellisense, class-library, visual-studio-2017

After migrating a VS2015 MVC Core application with two projects (web app and class library) to VS2017 I've lost intellisense on all views within the class library. Pretty much everything in every single view is broken, so I'm sure it's something fairly basic that the migration tool didn't take care of for me. Even the `@model` directive in each razor view is an error.

The `csproj` looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>Library</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>Library</PackageId>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\**" Exclude="bin\**;obj\**;**\*.xproj;packages\**;@(EmbeddedResource)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I tried duplicating the `web.config` from the web application to the root of the class library but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things were required to fix this issue, a change to the project SDK (`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`) and adding an element to set the output type to a library (`<OutputType>Library</OutputType>`). Full information on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5975) I cross-posted.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AssemblyName>Library</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>Library</PackageId>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\**" Exclude="bin\**;obj\**;**\*.xproj;packages\**;@(EmbeddedResource)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've hit this bug:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5975

Old Answer below

---

With the RTM version of VS 2017, you need to install the [Razor Language Service extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.RazorLanguageServices) to get back your Razor intellisense.

Unfortunately this component missed an internal ship date and as such did not make it as part of the actual VS 2017 release.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have that extension installed (just double checked by trying to reinstall - it reports that it is already installed on all compatible products). It was my understanding that the extension you linked was only for tag helper intellisense. I have lost intellisense on *everything*, and only in the class library.

Comment: Yeah, that's my issue. I'll self answer this question once we get a reasonable answer. At the moment the suggested fix actually breaks the build process, so having no intellisense is the lesser of two evils!

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the Razor Language Services by going to "Tools" > "Extensions and Updates".

Restart Visual Studio as per indication...

Reinstall Razor Language Services.

You will see razor intellisense working again such as asp-* tag helpers...