# How to control assembly generation for cshtml files in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, compilation, .net-assembly

My understanding is that several assemblies are produced by the compiler for ASP.NET MVC application:

1. All code in `App_Code` is compiled into its own dll.
2. Individual `view.cshtml` files located inside `Views` folder are compiled each into their own separate assembly.

In that regard a few questions:

1. Is there a way to produce just one assembly (preferably by merging 1 and 2 above, or at least by compiling all `cshtml` views into one assembly)?
2. Is there a way to control assembly name, version?
3. Are there any web.config settings that specifically control this on-demand compilation of cshtml files and files in the App_Code folder?

The reason I need more control is because I would like to use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute on my shred class library, so that I can use its functionality from my cshtml files (I cannot set accessibility level to `public` for my own reasons, so they have to remain `internal`, and I do not want to deal with conditional compilation either).

Comment: **Cshtml** files are open source.You can hide your code in **Actionresult** and transfer to view the result by **viewbag**

Answer (score 0):

You could change your routing, create a custom class to inherit from the `RazorViewEngine` class and add the `assembly` attribute. [Assembly Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w8c1y2s(v=vs.110).aspx). More on how to create your custom class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24344701/5138921)