# Asp.Net MVC Application split into multiple assemblies

Tags: asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I am pretty new to mvc but have already read a few books.
What I want to archive is:
-> Having the main asp.net app in its own project.
-> Every modul (for example forum modul) is hosted in a regular dll (including its controller, models and views).

I've looked into the issue of hosting controllers in different assemblies. This is actually easy to handle. But what I do have issues with are the views.
I could not find any resource regarding how to tell mvc that he should look for the views in this namespace the the other view in the other namespace.

Best regards
Simon

Comment: You haven't said what version of MVC you are using.. this is important.  The possible solutions are different.  For instance, if you're using MVC5 then you can look into the MVC Futures project and something called Portable Areas, but I don't think this has been ported to MVC Core.

Comment: Hi. I am working with MVC 5 and visual Studio 2015 prof. Thank you I will check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the projects/assemblies in the project you need to use them?
Look in the References folder. They must be there so you can use them.

Comment: Yes I added the references.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite clear why you would use this style of architecture, but again that's your choice. 
What I can confirm is that it is not going to be as useful as you think.

A detailed explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341336/is-it-possible-to-access-mvc-views-located-in-another-project)