# MVC - Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341336/is-it-possible-to-access-mvc-views-located-in-another-project) **Mohsen Esmailpour**'s answer, to build a sample project to load views and controllers from a class library using custom view engine.

Here's what I did,

1. Add a Asp.Net MVC project
2. Add a class library. Add references to

   - Microsoft.AspNet.Razor
   - Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages
   - Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
   - Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc"

Reference class library in MVC project. 
3. Add a "Controllers" folder and added "MyViewController.cs" class

```
public class MyViewController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

View engine (which should be causing the problem), I am not entirely sure what's happening here,

```
public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public CustomViewEngine()
    {
        MasterLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/bin/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/bin/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
    }
}
```

Route.config for the Mvc project,

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(name: "Route2", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            namespaces: new[] { "Custom.Views.Controllers" },
            defaults: new { controller = "MyView", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

4. Add Views folder and added "MyView.cshtml" (Views/MyView/Index.cshtml), also I set the Properties of this cshtml to "Copy to Output Directory" as "Copy Always" so that it appears in web project / bin/MyView/Index.cshtml.

[image]

When I run the project, http://localhost:/MyView, it hits the "MyView" controller, but not finding the "MyView" view.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be
>   greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument
>   list.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to
>   zero and less than the size of the argument list.]
>   System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider,
>   String format, ParamsArray args) +1876
>   System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format,
>   ParamsArray args) +58    System.String.Format(IFormatProvider
>   provider, String format, Object[] args) +80
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewLocation.Format(String viewName, String
>   controllerName, String areaName) +70
>   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String
>   controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]&
>   searchedLocations) +166
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String
>   locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String
>   cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations) +626
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean
>   useCache) +130
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<FindView>b__1(IViewEngine e) +24
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean
>   trackSearchedPaths) +85
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName) +183
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) +84
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +126    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3()
>   +198    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Controller controller) +13
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +583    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +173

Seems like I am missing something.

not sure what ""~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml" configurations doing and it seems failing in CustomViewEngine.

Comment: Solved this one by myself. Issue was ViewLocationFormats  configuration not correct in CustomViewEngine which I corrected as "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml" and started working. After doing that I noticed I have to include "@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage" in the Index.cshtml and it loaded my custom view. Hooray!

Comment: It would be great if you could post the solution as an answer.

Comment: @Dhanuka777 - could you post your full solution to this - I'm getting the same error trying to use a custom RazorViewEngine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in the folder's name, the folder in which my view was located.