# Rendering View from Separate project using DLL

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am learning on how to render a view from a separate project into my current project. It is possible to render a view that using a DLL came from another project?. I embed the DLL into my `References` so I can access the project. But my problem now is how can I call that view that I want to view in my current project.

What I tried so far:

In my view I call the DLL that I embeded `(eg: tryNewDLL)` by using `@using tryNewDLL;` in the header of my view. But I don't know the next step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to access MVC Views located in another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341336/is-it-possible-to-access-mvc-views-located-in-another-project)

Comment: views does not compile inside dll library.