# How to call views in other solutions

Tags: c#, .net

new job, new giant website made of multiple solutions, I have to develop a new page:
I'm in solution A, I want to load a view in solution B... How does this work, its my first experience with multiple solutions websites.
both solutions are in asp.net c# mvc

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341336/is-it-possible-to-access-mvc-views-located-in-another-project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to access MVC Views located in another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341336/is-it-possible-to-access-mvc-views-located-in-another-project)

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you are working within an existing codebase with plenty of examples? This question is fairly vague, but my assumption would be that your views are being routed by a controller which determines the URL of the page. I can't tell based on your tags though.

If this is the case, then it doesn't matter how many projects are running as long as you hit that URL. The controller acts as an API and will handle the request as long as that project is running. At my job we run a composite application using ASP.NET Core with a dedicated "content discovery" project which acts as a middleware API for handling all route requests from all (and we have a lot) of our various projects that are working together but it doesn't need to be that complicated.