# ASP.Net Can't find view from other project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 projects in same solution, let's say **ProjectA** and **ProjectB**. I've added **ProjectB** in references for **ProjectA**.

What I want to achieve is when I run **ProjectA** to actually run Index action of HomeController of **ProjectB**.

What I did for now is added **ProjectB** in namespaces for routes.MapRoute(...) for HomeController in **ProjectA** and it calls HomeController from **ProjectB**. But the problem is, when it wants to return the view, it tries to find it in **ProjectA**, not in **ProjectB**.

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to access MVC Views located in another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341336/is-it-possible-to-access-mvc-views-located-in-another-project)

Comment: I tried that but couldn't achieve much. :/