# Can't access views from different project using Razor View Engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, viewengine

I have a use case where I have many web projects that all use the same management general-purpose web pages, so I started to isolate my views to a separate project where all solutions can reference and use.

Because currently, I have to copy-paste the view files across solutions whenever I have a new change.

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24344701/5077196), I added a new custom view engine, and then added the path to the location where my views live (in a separate project beside my main project).

```
    public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        public CustomViewEngine()
        {
            MasterLocationFormats = new string[]
            {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",
        "~/Shared.Views/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Shared.Views/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",

            };
            ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
            {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",
        "~/../Shared.Views/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
        "~/../Shared.Views/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
            };
      }
    }
```

When including the following:

```
"~/../Shared.Views/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
"~/../Shared.Views/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
```

I am getting the following exception:

> Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory. Description:
> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
> web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
> the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Cannot use a leading ..
> to exit above the top directory.

My file structure.

```
Solution
   Shared.Views
      Views
         Profiles
            create.cshtml
            delete.cshtml
            edit.cshtml
            details.cshtml
   MainProject
      Global.asax
```

What is the correct path I have to add to tell MVC to look for views in my separate project?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t reference files in another project like you’re doing. Check out [Razor Class Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) if you’re using ASPNET Core 2.1+