# Is there a way to use a partial MVC view from a different drive, using the full path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently creating an MVC ASP.NET application in which multiple widgets are loaded from a different location. I have most of the logic down, but I get stuck trying to load the widgets from a differnt location than the original one.

Everything was working when I used this

```
foreach (WidgetPrototype.Models.Widget widget in Model)
    {
        <blockquote style="border-style: outset">
            @Html.Partial(widget.Name)
        </blockquote>
    }
```

But when I moved the files to test loading views from a different location, changing my code to

```
foreach (WidgetPrototype.Models.Widget widget in Model)
    {
        <blockquote style="border-style: outset">
            @Html.Partial(@"D:\" + widget.Name + ".cshtml")
        </blockquote>
    }
```

It stopped working, and gave the error that the view could not be found, with the message:

> [InvalidOperationException: The partial view 'D:\Clock.cshtml' was not
>   found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following
>   locations were searched: 
>   ~/Views/Widgets/D:\Clock.cshtml.aspx
>   ~/Views/Widgets/D:\Clock.cshtml.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/D:\Clock.cshtml.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/D:\Clock.cshtml.ascx
>   ~/Views/Widgets/D:\Clock.cshtml.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Widgets/D:\Clock.cshtml.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/D:\Clock.cshtml.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/D:\Clock.cshtml.vbhtml]

So apparently it's still trying to find the files on a relative path in the project.

Is there a way to force it to just use the full path?

Comment: Unsure if I understood (re: `D:\ `) - paths are relative to _your application_ (not just "any" location in your/server file system). Your app/IIS doesn't have permissions to just access/serve resources from any location in a file system without configuration...Hth.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried specifying the relative path?
E.g.
 `@Html.Partial("../MyViews/_PartialView", Model)` ?

Would also recommend using `@Html.RenderPartial` as it works faster.

Comment: I can't use a relative path as the views are on a different drive.

Comment: From what I've researched, you can create your own "custom" `RazorViewEngine` and specify paths to look in. Could it help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838766/how-do-i-implement-a-custom-razorviewengine-to-find-views-in-non-standard-locati