# Asp.NET MVC3 - Access Area's Controller Without Area in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I created a web application with ASP.NET MVC3 Framework. In project,I add new area called Administrator with HomeController and Index action.

It work with
`http://localhost:2813/Administrator/Home/Index`

But when I try access with URL
`http://localhost:2813/Home/Index`

I get a error message :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched > > > locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web > > > request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it > originated in the code.

I alse add namespace in maproute but it still not work.
Anyone has idea? Thanks.

Update question:

This is MapRoute in Global.ascx
 `routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "SampleWebsite.Controllers" }
            );`

and this is AdministratorAreaRegistration.ascx
`context.MapRoute(
                "Administrator",
                "Administrator/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { area = "Administrator", controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "SampleWebsite.Areas.Administrator.Controllers" }
            );`

**EDIT**
Problem was resolved if I move MapRoute from Global to AdministratorAreaRegistration (I can not understand and explain its)
`context.MapRoute(
                "Administrator",
                "Administrator/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { area = "Administrator", controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "SampleWebsite.Areas.Administrator.Controllers" }
            );`
            `context.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { area = "", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
                namespaces: new[] { "SampleWebsite.Controllers" }
            );`

Now, all request to `localhost/Home/Index` will be response 404 not found. Only request with exactly area name (Administrator) allowed.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Can we see your route definitions? (MapRoute) I'd like to see the routes from the Global.asax but also the routes from the AreaRegistration please.

Comment: MapRoute was added. Did I miss anything there?

Answer (score 2):

When you use the url `/Home/Index` you are not going through the area. An area is defined in your routing with an `Administrator` prefix and it is the presence of this prefix in the url that allows the routing engine to recognize that you are inside the area.

There are some [possible workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2172349/29407) to have a default area.

Comment: I just read your recommend link and think that may be work for my problem.Thanks you!

Comment: I juss had free time to try this solution. It is great work but I think it far from ideal. My problem is If i try access with `localhost:2813/Home/Index`, it should redirect to 404 not found instead of go to HomeController of Admin Area.

Answer (score 1):

If you need start page inside area, consider this in HomeController of default area (`/Controllers/HomeController.cs`):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home",
            new { area = "Administrator" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for adding the routes. If what you want is using your admin area when there is no area specified in url, you can try replacing your route in the Global.asax with:

```
routes.MapRoute( "Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { area = "Administrator", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new[] { "SampleWebsite.Areas.Administrator.Controllers" } );
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I access to `http://localhost/Home/Index`, this route will redirect to `http://localhost/Administrator/Home/Index`, is it right? But in this, I want `http://localhost/Home/Index` redirect to error 404 : page not found. This controller is only owned by Administrator. Default controllers of project does not have HomeController.

Comment: No there won't be a redirect. The action from the Admin area will be called. If you try to handle access rights, this is not the good way. Areas are not meant for this. Try looking at the authorization filters if this is wat you want.