# How to make areas available in homepage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a second thing in my RouteConfig:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
```

I need to change controller, but the problem is that it is placed in Areas.
I tried to change MapRoute to this:

```
url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { area="Purchase", controller = "Card", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

but it's not working.

Also I have this in AreaRegistration:

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Purchase_default",
            string.Format("{0}/{{controller}}/{{action}}/{{id}}", AreaNames.Purchase),
            new { controller = "Card", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175736/how-to-set-area-view-as-home-page-in-asp-net-mvc) I have seen something similar but I didn't got how to use it.

What am I doing wrong and how should it be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "make the areas available on the home page"?

Comment: By another words, I want to took controller from area, but I want to describe it in RouteConfig.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to do either.