# ASP.NET MVC 4: Default Route in other Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to set the default route for **~/** to the *Area* **OnlineUser**:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                            area="OnlineUser", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

However it errors out indicating that going to the root "/" of the site is an exception because ti can't find a controller/action.

Am I setting the Area wrong?

I have a Home and Index in the Area and can get to the Area nicely via its route:

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "OnlineUser_default",
            "OnlineUser/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The Exact error is:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the 
searched locations. The following locations were searched: 
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx ~/Views/Home/Index.ascx 
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx 
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml ~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml 
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

Comment: What does the area registration class look like? Is this the only route in the application?

Comment: I have a Home and Index in the Area and can get to the Area nicely via its route.

Comment: @steve ->            context.MapRoute(
                "OnlineUser_default",
                "OnlineUser/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140208/how-to-set-a-default-route-to-an-area-in-mvc