# How to choose specific folder for mvc controller and view folders?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

i want to integrate mvc2 into an existing webforms project. to get this work, i found all information online.

now i have the problem that mvc just works when the controller and views folder are placed in the root, but i want to have a specific folder (like 'mvc') so that the controller and views folder are placed like this:

~/mvc/controller

~/mvc/views

is this possible or do i have to use mvc area to solve this issue?!

thanks for your help!

best regards...

Comment: The million dollar question is, "have you tried it already"? When you say integrate are you planning to have webforms and mvc in one project or separate projects deployed as a single (sub) application in IIS?

Comment: i have integrated already my mvc views and controllers and everything works, but only when they are placed in root. now i want them in a seperate folder.

Comment: and yes, i am planning to have webforms and mvc in one project, thats why i have integrated mvc in old webforms project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group all of your MVC work together, I would use areas to accomplish this.

I think it is possible though to override the View Engine to point the default root to a different folder. This is detailed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2172349/2099977) post.

Something to think about before doing this though is, are you planning to eventually migrate your WebForms to Asp.net MVC and remove your WebForms work? If so you might be better keeping the root Controllers and Views folders in the project root.