# ASP.Net MVC default url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect from "mysite.com" to "mysite.com/home/index" (option of default route)
if someone enters only the domain name in browser.

surely it can be done overriding begin request method in global.asax, but i think there must be some kind of route of web.config options.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006673/asp-net-mvc-default-url-view as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the default route to a new action called `RedirectToIndex` or similar which just redirects to `Index`.

No mess in `global.asax` and it's easy to tell what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some URL redirecting via URL Rewrite (IIS), there is no way to do this via Web.Config or Route.