# Asp.net Mvc areas routing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I want default page of the site to be Login.cshtml. I get the Exception:

> Error: The view 'LogIn' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

I have 2 areas. Structure is shown below.

[image]

My routeconfig is shown below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Portal.Web
{
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "LogIn", id =   UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Portal.Web.Areas.Management" }
        );
    }
    }

}
```

My global.asax.cs is shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Portal.Web
{
// Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
// visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
}
```

`Have you any advice?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I followed instruction in this post. And problem is resolved. Visit [ASP.NET MVC Default URL View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006673/asp-net-mvc-default-url-view)

Thank you all.

Comment: There is no definitive answer at that url. what did you finally do ? Change ``defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "LogIn", id =   UrlParameter.Optional }`` to ``defaults: new { area = "management", controller = "Home", action = "LogIn", id =   UrlParameter.Optional }`` ?

Comment: Without any link to a direct solution this is not worth much to anyone.

Comment: I had the same issue and I solved my problem resolving the namespace of my web application. I move my controllers from no area to Admin Area and didn't work, when i adjust the namespace of all class it worked

Comment: @renefc3 Why did the namespace have to be changed?  Maybe you can help me here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450549/want-to-understand-process-for-troubleshooting-asp-net-mvc-routing-failure

Answer (score 7):

You forgot some stuff

Recap:

`ManagementAreaRegistration.cs`

```
public class ManagementAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Management";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Management_default",
            "Management/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

`RouteConfig.cs`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default" // Route name
        , "{controller}/{action}/{id}" // URL with parameters
        , new { area = "management", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        , new[] { "Portal.Web.Areas.Management.Controllers" } // Namespace of controllers in root area
    );
}
```

You set `Portal.Web.Areas.Management` when it should be `Portal.Web.Areas.Management.Controllers`  also it is missing the default area: `area = "management"`

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you need to change your namespace on the `MapRoute` from:

```
Portal.Web.Areas.Management
```

To:

```
Portal.Web.Areas.Management.Controllers
```

Answer (score -1):

Clear out your bin folder and rebuild. There is a chance there is an old dll set up with the old routing. This worked for me for one route at least.