# Getting error 404 not found with ASP.NET MVC Area routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having a problem with an Area route in MVC 5.  When I browse to /Evernote/EvernoteAuth I get a 404 resource cannot be found error.

My area looks like this:

```
Areas
    Evernote
        Controllers
            EvernoteAuthController
        Views
            EvernoteAuth
                Index.cshtml
```

The EvernoteAreaRegistration.cs (UPDATE: RegisterArea() wasn't being called so I did a Clean and Rebuild.  Now it is called but same result.) contains this route map:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
     context.MapRoute(
        "Evernote_default",
        "Evernote/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
}
```

The EvernoteAuthController's Index() method simply returns View().

My application's RouteConfig.cs currently has no route maps defined, but I tried manually "forcing" it here by implementing this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "EvernoteAuthorization",
    url: "Evernote/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "EvernoteAuth", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "AysncOAuth.Evernote.Simple.SampleMVC.Controllers" }
);
```

but I get the same results whether this route map exists or is commented out.

Using Phil Haack's [asp.net mvc routing debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/) I saw that my routes matched fine and the area name, controller name and Action method names matched.  I put breakpoints in the controller action methods and those methods were never entered.  UPDATE: Those methods were never entered when browsing to /Evernote/EvernoteAuth however when I browsed to just the area name, /Evernote, an EvernoteAuthController was instantiated and the Index() method was called.  (Why is that controller being instantiated by /Evernote by not by /Evernote/EvernoteAuth?)  Then I received the error:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/EvernoteAuth/Index.aspx
~/Views/EvernoteAuth/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/EvernoteAuth/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
and so on...
```

In this case I believe ~ = / (application root).  So the area `Areas\Evernote\Views` is not being searched.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is important tha you add the correct namespace to your controller

```
  namespace YourDefaultNamespace.Areas.Evernote.Controllers
  {
    public class EvernoteAuthController : Controller
    { 
        ...
        ...
    }
  }
```

So the routing can find your controller.
Now you have to register the area in the  Global.asax.cs with the method

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

Comment: Thanks; When copying an existing controller from a different project that caused my error. The namespace was important & needed to be correct.

Comment: OMG! This has just solved me a huge problem I had for around 2 hours!!! Of course! This is common sense! I moved a controller from the controller's folder to an area and I was wondering why it did not work! Now ti does :D Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6):

Be careful with `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` inside `Application_Start` method.

If you put `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` to be last inside `Application_Start` that will not work.

Put `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` to be first and routing will be successfully executed..

**Example:**

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();  //<--- Here work

        FilterConfig.Configure(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.Configure(RouteTable.Routes);

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();  //<--- Here not work
 }
```

Comment: Your answer led me to realise my `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` was commented out. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Like you found in my post at http://legacy.piranhacms.org/the-magic-of-mvc-routing-with-multiple-areas you probably figured out the **all** controllers are mapped to the default route (i.e the one you added manually in your route config). If it has been added to the default route, then it will search the location for the default route for its views, i.e `~/Views/...`

So the error really seems to be that the **Area** isn't configured properly. Make sure that you have the following line in your Global.asax.xs:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

This is the line that actually sets up the areas and makes sure that when a controller within a area is hit, the view directory of that area is searched, in your case `~/Areas/Evernote/Views`. The thing covered in my blog post was how to eliminate that controllers from your Evernote area are being mapped in the default route.

Hope this help!

Regards

Håkan

Comment: @haken Thank you for answering. I've stepped through the code and my new area is indeed registering.

Comment: I found my problem. My controller class' namespace did not match the Area structure. When I changed the namespace to Areas.Evernote.Controllers it worked. I was surprised about this - why would this be a requirement? Or, perhaps it is not a requirement but I have some default set?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the order of the configuration in Application_Start of global.asax.cs was

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Changing the order made it work.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```