# MVC 5 Admin Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm in the middle of migrating a WebForms project into MVC 5 with the ultimate goal of getting it to .NET Core 2.

I'm looking at using the Area functionality in MVC and want to have an Admin area which will have the same controller(s) as the non-admin version i.e. /Blog/Index and /Admin/Blog/Index.

I've followed some tutorials and I'm getting a 404 error on /Admin/, I've tried other route values i.e. /Admin/Home/ and /Admin/Home/Index all result in a 404 error.

I suspect I need to create another area for the non-admin pages so that all pages are within an area but I'm not sure.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
---- Areas
|      |
|      |---- Admin
|              |--- Controllers
|              |      |---- HomeController
|              |--- Views
|                     |--- Index
|----Controllers
|      |----HomeController
|
|----Views
       |--- Index
```

I've assigned the namespace in AdminAreaRegistration.cs and RouteConfig.cs as follows:

AdminAreaRegistration.cs

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication1.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
);
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication1.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: can you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450549/getting-error-404-not-found-with-asp-net-mvc-area-routing) thread similar to your

Comment: @DhavalPankhaniya Thanks for the link, as per the post I checked the namespaces were correct which they were and I still had an issue but for good measure I remade my test application and that now works just how it should.  I must have missed something but I'm not sure what!!!